# wxWidgets with Codeblocks setup

Tags: codeblocks, wxwidgets, mingw-w64

So im trying to get wxwidgets up and running with codeblocks.
I have installed mingw
I also compiled widgets
My environment PATH variables have also been set up correctly

but whenever I try to build a wxWidgets project from code blocks i get the error

```
||=== Build: Release in test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
ld.exe||cannot find -lwxmsw_core|
ld.exe||cannot find -lwxbase|
ld.exe||cannot find -lwxpng|
ld.exe||cannot find -lwxzlib|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 5 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 9 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: you need to set up the linker options in C::B. Please refer to different wxforum postings on how to do that.

Comment: Do you still have this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have improperly configured the Linker.

You can get the linker settings using MSYS. Go to your wxwidgets folder and type this in MSYS: `wx-config --libs > /c/settings.txt`. This will generate a text file in the C: drive with the linker settings. You can also use `--cxxflags` to get the compiler settings.

Comment: Not needed a different compiler. What's that about a *linker flag order*? I've never heard about that.

Comment: @Ripi2 The linker flag order is the order in which flags are given to the linker. When using wxWidgets there are some special settings that you have to give to the linker. Usually they are the first flags to be given to the linker. There is a bug in MinGw that requires giving them after the  other flags (output location, input location, etc.). First try configuring wxWidgets according to an online tutorial then see if you have this issue.

Comment: I know about order of static libraries issue (not a bug), for example read [this](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/specify_the_libraries_for_the_linker_to_use). But I know nothing about *flags order*. Can you show a link to that bug?

Comment: @Ripi2 I looked at the link and that is what I was talking about, sorry for the confusion. I was using the wrong words.

Comment: Anyhow, for MinGW or TDM.GCC CodeBlocks uses the right order of such flags. The user must set the right order of static libraries.

Comment: @Ripi2 I think my IDE doesn't use the correct order, as I had to configure it myself. There are some special settings you need to use. Can you check online for how to configure them (try using MSYS if you're on Windows).

Comment: I have no experience mixing MSYS and C::B. I don't think it's a easy mix. MSYS is a unix-like command-box. An IDE is a different animal.

Comment: @Ripi2 You don't need to mix them. Navigate to your wxWidgets folder in MSYS and type "wxwidgets --libs > /c/libsettings.txt". This will write the settings to a text file in your C:/ drive. You can then use these settings with the linker.

Comment: Why do you ask me? I'm not the OP and I have no problems with C::B

Comment: @Ripi2 Oh. Sorry, I didn't notice you weren't the OP.